# Meaning of "お戯れを"?

Tags: meaning, words, archaic-language, role-language

Can someone tell me what "お戯れを" means? I came across this in a Japanese drama. I can't quite figure out if this is almost like a formal and polite request to make somebody stop 'kidding around' or if it's something else completely. In what context can this be used?

Answer (score 8):

お[戯]{たわむ}れを is mainly heard in samurai dramas. Typically, a samurai or a maid says this to their master in the sense of "You must be joking" or "You're not serious, are you?" In dramas set in modern Japan, an old butler- or detective-like character may say this, too.

A more common equivalent in modern Japanese is ご冗談を.

**EDIT:** You may be wondering which verb is omitted after を, but there are no "long" versions of these expressions.

Comment: Suggest changing 'owner' to 'master'.

Comment: Even if there’s no actual longer expression, isn’t the verb implicitly 言う? (Although it’d be unclear how to conjugate it.)

Comment: Is this pronounced as おじゃれ or おたわむれ?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I'm not sure,.. We say 嘘を言え, but 嘘を makes no sense. We say ご冗談を, but ご冗談を言え makes no sense to me.

Comment: @istrasci Chocolate added the reading :)

Comment: @naruto たしかに… 笑